# win cmd - A string in a text file to be read while being run in a command

Tags: windows, cmd

I remember doing this exercise back in college, but I can't recall exactly how o do this.

You save a string (could be your password, certain input shortcuts, etc) in a text file. Then, with your cmd prompt, you write your command, but instead of manually typing out the string (in this case, its a LONG string and randomized), you load it from the said text file automatically and when executing the command, it will read the content of the text file to automatically input for you.

Comment: What should it do with the string it reads, you want it to fill a form somewhere?

Comment: I want it to make it easier to type into the prompt.

Let's say the command is "login username xeph password os".
I want to instead type "login username [username.txt] password [password.txt" and still do the same

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that this is **NOT** a good thing to do with a password.

Put the password into a file.

```
ECHO>magic.txt wh2084nJ)&322ng0adf
```

Get the password back from the file and use it.

```
SET /P "MYPASSWORD=" <magic.txt
ECHO %MYPASSWORD%
```

EDIT:

Create a .bat script called RUNMYPROGRAM.bat with the following contents.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P "USERNAME=" <username.txt
SET /P "PASSWORD=" <password.txt

login username %USERNAME% password %PASSWORD%
```

Comment: I am aware it isn't a good thing for a password. But how about tokens or long strings of code used as an identifier when accessing an online feature? Also, my assumption, I don't think that's supposed to be typed into the cmd prompt?